# Voltar para mesma página depois da crud de uma modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma pagina com uma datatables, no evento select desta tabela abra uma modal passando o id do registro selecionado para modal, na modal eu faço a exclusão deste registro, logo após eu fecho a modal e redireciono para a pagina que estava anteriormente, porem a tabela fica vazia, ou seja, não atualizou com os novos registros.

Tabela:
JavaScript

```
$('#TabEvolucao').DataTable({
        "processing" : true, 
        "select": true      ,
        "ajax" : {
            "type" : "POST",
            "url" : "estrutura/tabevolucao.php",
            dataSrc : '',
            "data" : function(d){
                d.idcliente = vlsidcliente;
                d.acao = "select";
                }
        },
        "columns" : [   {"data" : "id"}, 
                        {"data" : "data"}, 
                        {"data" : "descricao"},
                        {"data" : "nome"},
                        {"data" : "ativo"}
                    ],      
        "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
         "iDisplayLength": 7,
         "bFilter": true,
         "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],              
        "language": {               
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página ",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
                },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }
            }   

    });
```

Enviando dados do registro selecionado para modal:
JavaScript

```
var table = $('#TabEvolucao').DataTable();
    table
        .on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
            var rowData = table.rows( indexes ).data().toArray();
            //events.prepend( '<div><b>'+type+' selection</b> - '+JSON.stringify( rowData )+'</div>' );
            //var dt = JSON.stringify( rowData );

            var id = rowData["0"].id; 

            document.getElementById('idevolucao').value = id;

            $('#modalVWEVOLUCAO').data('id', id).modal('show');


        } )
```

Botão excluir na MODAL
JavaScript

```
$('#btnUpdateYesEVO').click(function () {
        var id = $('#myModalUpdateEVO').data('id');         
        var idevolucao = document.getElementById('idevolucao').value;
        var descricaoevolucao = document.getElementById('descricaoevolucao').value;
        var boatao = document.getElementById('acaobotaoevolucao').value;
        var iduser=$('#iduser').val();

        if(boatao == 'DESATIVAR'){

            $.post('estrutura/excluirevolucao.php',{
                    acao:'delete',
                    id:id,
                    user_id:iduser                  
                    },function(r) { 
                       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
                       if (m.success) {

                        $('#myModalUpdateEVO').modal('hide');
                        toastr["success"](m.msg);             
                        $("#listevolucao").load(location.href + " #listevolucao>", "");//<<<<<< esta aqui o problema    

                       } else {            
                        toastr["error"](m.msg);
                        $('#myModalUpdateEVO').modal('hide');

                       }             
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Confundir Java com Javascript é a mesma coisa que confundir cachorro com cachorro-quente. A sua pergunta é sobre Javascript, e não sobre Java.

Comment: Tudo bem Victor, consegue ajudar nessa pergunta?

Comment: Descobri, basta atualizar a tabela.. $('#TabEvolucao').DataTable().ajax.reload();

Comment: Então poste a sua solução como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segue solução:

```
$('#TabEvolucao').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Como ficou meu código:

```
$('#btnaddEVO').click(function () {
        var id = $('#modalADDEVO').data('id');          
        var adddataevolucao = $('#adddataevolucao').val();
        var adddescricaoevolucao =$('#adddescricaoevolucao').val();     
        var iduser=$('#iduser').val();

        $.post('estrutura/adicionaevolucao.php',{
                    acao:'insert',
                    id:id,
                    user_id:iduser,     
                    data:adddataevolucao,       
                    descricao:adddescricaoevolucao
                    },function(r) { 
                       var m = jQuery.parseJSON(r);        
                       if (m.success) {

                        $('#modalADDEVO').modal('hide');
                        toastr["success"](m.msg);             
                        $('#TabEvolucao').DataTable().ajax.reload();


                       } else {            
                        toastr["error"](m.msg);
                        $('#modalADDEVO').modal('hide');

                       }             
                    });

    });
```

Comment: Lembre-se só que se vc inicializar o DataTable novamente ele recria a lista e isso pode perder alguma propriedade que vc colocou, por exemplo, de ordenação na inicializacao.